# How can I concatenate a one string in a colum with every element in its corresponding row using formulas in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table from which, I need to concatenate the first string of every row with every string its row. I need these transposed so I can get unique IDs from it.

Data:
[This is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYNI0.png)
[This is the output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Lch.png)

I tried transposing the rows to columns in another sheet, then running a concatenate function. Even with the transpose, I don't know how to ensure all transposed rows come one under the other.
For my current use, the table will keep growing over time and I'll need to keep creating unique IDs, so ideally I'd like a single cell formula that will do this for me.

If I can do this without AppScript, that'll be even better. I am not a specialist in this domain and I don't need to build this skill. I just need a quick method do this for a growing data set.

Much thanks to any who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(A2:A4&E2:C4))
```

Comment: Hello z.. Thank you so much! The solution worked perfectly! You saved me a lot of time. :D